# Creating PDF With FPDF using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

Here is my button :

```
<button onclick="GeneratePDF()" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:2%;width:20%;">Generate Report</button>
```

Here is my Javascript :

```
function GeneratePDF(){      
    $.get("function_and_ajax/ajax.php", {
        ajx: "GeneratePDF"
    }, function (result) {

    });
}
```

My jquery :

```
if($_GET['ajx'] == "GeneratePDF"){   
      GeneratePDF($type,$start,$end);
}
```

My PHP Function :

```
 function GeneratePDF($type,$start,$end){
                $pdf= new FPDF();
                $pdf->SetAuthor('Lombok Idjoe Kediri');

                $pdf->SetAuthor('Lana Kovacevic');
                $pdf->SetTitle('FPDF tutorial');

                $pdf->SetXY (10,50);
                $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
                $pdf->Write(5,'Congratulations! You have generated a PDF.');

                //Output the document
                $pdf->Output('example1.pdf','I');
}
```

when i clicked my button, nothing happen...

Comment: is this `if($_GET['ajx'] == "GeneratePDF"){   
      GeneratePDF($type,$start,$end);
}` in your jquery or php?

Comment: its on my jquery

Comment: can you check if there is a ajax request in `network tab` of your browser. Also check if there is any console error